# Angular - When Background/Area outside a div tapped

Tags: angularjs

I've been reading around and can't find an answer to something i thought would be obvious.

I have a menu button that shows/hides a small div pane containing 2 buttons. I'm using `ng-click="main.showLogoutDiv = !main.showLogoutDiv"` to toggle between the 2 states.

However I would also like it if anywhere outside that div is clicked, I can toggle that boolean `showLogoutDiv`.

Is there something in Angular that lets me check for this?

Thanks.

(btw - i've made my own 'popup pane' - like this screenshot - as I couldn't find anything existing in Angular - have I missed something that comes out the box).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the Angular [**click outside**](https://github.com/IamAdamJowett/angular-click-outside) directive by Adam Jowett. You use it on an element like this:

```
<button id="my-button">Menu Trigger Button</button>
<div ng-controller="MenuController">
    <div class="menu" id="main-menu" click-outside="closeThis()" outside-if-not="my-button">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

When a user clicks anywhere outside of that `<div>`, the `closeThis()` function in your controller will execute. But if the user clicks on the `my-button` element, that won't count as a `click-outside`. This lets you define elements that should be ignored.

Your `click-outside` function might have code like this:

```
function MenuController($scope) {
    $scope.closeThis = function () {
        showLogoutDiv = false;
    }
}
```

Or you could keep things simpler by not using a scope function and just specifying the `showLogoutDiv = false` in your HTML using this form:

```
<div ng-controller="MenuController">
    <div class="menu" id="main-menu" click-outside="showLogoutDiv=false">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect - great directive :-)